# The limite of borel mesurable functions are borel mesurable

Tags: measure-theory

I have problems with this: If $\{f_n\}$ are measurable functions from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$, then 
$$f(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(\omega),  & \text{if the limit exists} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
is measurable in the same sigma fields $(\mathcal{F},B(\mathbb{R}))$. I know that the set $ B = \{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(\omega) \text{ exists} \} \in \mathcal{F}$. So
$$f = (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n) 1_B$$
and la indicator function $1_B$ is measurable but I can't continue. Any help? Thanks

Comment: You mean $B \in \mathcal F$ above , not $B(\mathbb R)$, right?

Comment: Yes. It would be $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we know that the set $\{\lim f_n \text{ exists}\} = B$ is measurable (i.e. in $\mathcal F$). By definition, we also have $B^c \in \mathcal F$.

All we are left to do is show that for any $y$, the set $\{f > y\}$ belongs to $\mathcal F$.

Let us perform some rewrites.Fix $\omega \in B$, so that the limit exists . In that case, note that $\lim f_n(\omega) > y$ if and only if : there exists $M,N_0 \in \mathbb N$, so that for all $N \geq N_0$ we have $f_N(\omega) > y+ \frac 1M$ (We need the $M$ to avoid a sequence decreasing to $y$ from above). The latter condition can be written in set notation : $$\bigcup_{M,N_0 \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{N \geq N_0} \left\{f_N(\omega) > y + \frac 1M\right\}$$

which is a countable union of countable intersections of sets in $\mathcal F$, hence is in $\mathcal F$. Hence, the set $B \cap \{f > y\}$ belongs to $\mathcal F$ for all $y$.

Now, if $y  \geq 0$ then $\{f > y\} \subset B$,so $\{f > y\}$ is itself mesurable.

If $y < 0$ then $\{f > y\} = (\{f >y \} \cap B^c) \cup (\{f > y\} \cap B)$. The latter set is measurable, and the first set is just $B^c$ since $B^c \subset \{f > y\}$,and so is measurable.

Hence, $f$ itself is measurable.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Keep the "limit-type" measurability argument in mind.